# Unresolved External Symbol __imp__Py_Finalize

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, linker

I literally just got Python.h to link to my Visual Studio 2017 IDE and then when I ran it, it spat this error out for me.

I use VS2017, and I am learning C++, so I have no idea why this is happening. I linked my Python.h file's directory in the project properties.

Full Build Logs:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: PyC++, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
1>PyC++.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__Py_Finalize
1>PyC++.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__Py_SetProgramName
1>PyC++.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__Py_InitializeEx
1>C:\Users\maste\source\repos\PyC++\Release\PyC++.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals
1>Done building project "PyC++.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to include `pythonxx.lib`(such as python26.lib) in your references.

Comment: I have included python38.lib (which is the version i'm using) my references, yet I am still getting this error

Comment: Are you linking 64-bit or 32-bit? Try  changing the solution platform to x64.

Comment: I was linking Win32, but when I changed it to x64, it said it couldn't open input file "python38.lib" despite the fact that I clearly added the include directory.

Comment: The include directory is for header files, python38.lib is a library file.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple, like @Xiaoying Sun has stated, put the python38.lib file in your references, however, you're required to put it in your VC++ directories, this way it will work.